# Evaluate the Integral: $\int\ x^2\ e^{x^3}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int\ x^2\ e^{x^3}\ dx$

Step one: eliminate the $x$'s from the problem. The only way this can be done is utilizing $u$-substitution $u=x^3$

$u=x^3$

$du=3x^2\ dx$

$3\int\ e^u\ du$

at this point I am confused. Can some one point me in the correct direction?

Comment: It is $\int \frac{1}{3}e^u\,du$, "because" $x^2\,dx=\frac{1}{3}\,du$.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{d}{dx} e^{x^{3}} = 3x^{2}e^{x^{3}}$$

Comment: Careful! You should have come up with 
$$
\frac 13 \int e^u du
$$

Comment: and what about the $x^2$ in the step 1 ?

Comment: I see my mistake. I forgot to do the trick of balancing the 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $\color{green}{u} = \color{magenta}{x^3}$ and $du = 3x^2 dx$, then $\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}du} = \color{blue}{x^2 dx}$, so
$$
\int x^2 e^{x^3}\;dx = \int e^{\color{magenta}{x^3}}\color{blue}{x^2 dx}
= \int e^{\color{green}{u}}\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}du}
$$
This integral is (without the colors)
$$
\frac{1}{3}\int e^u du = \frac{1}{3}e^u + C = \dots
$$

Comment: The problem with these types of questions are there is rarely an explanation as to how the $\frac{1}{3}$ appears.

Comment: @Cetshwayo: Do you now understand how the $\frac{1}{3}$ appears?

Comment: Yes. It has to do with the idea that multiplying the integral by one does not change its value; thus, $\frac{1}{3}\cdot 3=1$.

Comment: @Cetshwayo: That is a good way to say it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$\int e^u du$ means "the function(s) (of $u$) whose derivative is $e^u$".  Which function has a derivative of $e^u$?

Comment: Is the answer: $\frac{e^{x^3}}{3}+C$

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Your very last step is incorrect. You need to substitute $\frac{1}{3}{du} = {x^2 dx}$. Then you get $\frac{1}{3}\int e^u du$. The integral of this is $\frac{1}{3}(e^u) + c$, so the answer would be $\frac{1}{3}(e^{x^3}) + c$

Answer (score 0):

I would like to start with a step zero: what is the derivative of $e^{x^3}$?

Applying the chain rule we find: $3x^2e^{x^3}$.

That quite "looks like" $x^2e^{x^3}$.

Hmm, how to get rid of that constant $3$?

> by multiplying with $\frac13$ so the answer is $\frac13e^{x^3}+C$

Step zero makes step one redundant.